# Converting a boolean field to 'yes' or 'no' statement on select

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

We can convert a boolean field in MySql with

```
select if(bool_field_name, 'yes', 'no') ...
```

How can I do something like this in Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is `iif()`:

```
select iif(bool_field_name, 'yes', 'no')
```